# jQuery undefined error

Tags: jquery, session, prototype

I am working with session timeout in javascript.

I use this code for the timeout in my .js file:

```
var wintimeout;  
    function SetWinTimeout() {  
         intimeout = window.setTimeout("redirect();",g_secTimeout); //after 5 secs i.e. 5 * 1000  
    }   

      //$('body').click(function() {
      jQuery('body').click(function() {
        window.clearTimeout(wintimeout); //when user clicks remove timeout and reset it  
        SetWinTimeout();  
    });  

});
```

In my .php file I included the jquery source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!--script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.alerts-1.1/jquery.js"></script-->
```

I tried both of this..

But when I run it it still gives me the '$ is undefined' or 'jQuery is undefined' error for IE and FF.

Aside from jquery I am using the prototype library. In my other pages, it is working
which is also using jquery and protoype. But for these other pages it keeps giving me this error.
It gets really frustrating ;(

Can somebody help!

If this should matter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtm11/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: jQuery 1.2.6 is getting quite old...

Comment: How do the generated HTML look like? What is firebug/chrome dev tools saying?

Comment: I looked at the XHR tab of NET and it seemed that the jquery.js was called
successfully because it says 200 OK. But then when it comes to the line
where jQuery is called it stops and gives that runtime error..

In IE it says object required..

Comment: @Stefan ~ I'd say that `getting quite old` is an understatement.

Comment: It was released May 24th 2008 :)

Comment: i have downloaded the lates version and placed jQuery.noConflict(); at the top of my js file but still the error is there. It still says jQuery undefined.. the XHR of NET tab says that jquery was called because it has 200 ok status..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip a copy of your page down to the bare minimum; nothing in the `<body>`, just `<script src="path/to/jquery.js">` in the  plus the following inside its own `<script></script>` tags:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var wintimeout;
    function redirect(){
        alert('REDIRECT');
    }
    jQuery('body').click(function() {
        clearTimeout(wintimeout);
        wintimeout = setTimeout(redirect, 5000);
    });
});
```

If it still gives the same error, then it must be the path to the jQuery file; correct the path.

Once that's working, build the page up again by adding HTML, CSS and other javascript back in.

Comment: i tried this one.. i only had this function and my .php that contains the link to the source.. tried to write the absolute path but still it gives the error.. i dont understand ::(((((

Comment: You say other pages are working. Try starting with a stripped down copy of a working page - otherwise same process.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS Libraries might be conflicting. See the link below for more info on using jQuery with other libraries.

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest jQuery script (1.7) and store it in a separate folder in your workspace and specify the path of it in your <`script>` tag. You can download the latest version from [www.jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

Comment: i have downloaded the lates version and placed jQuery.noConflict(); at the top of my js file but still the error is there. It still says jQuery undefined.. the XHR of NET tab says that jquery was called because it has 200 ok status..

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons for this,

- The code cannot reach the URL that is being used to access the jQuery
  library.
- The jQuery library should be the declared before using any other
  JS/jQuery plug-ins and this should be done in head section of your
  page.
- Try pointing the library from your local disk/file (though not always better, but it might help sometimes)
- I am assuming that you are writing your code on document.load
- Always use the latest version of the library unless you have some
  explicit dependencies on previous versions